# How to split and join message for crypto?

Tags: java, encryption

The encrypt and decrypt althorithm often come with a "base-number" value, such as Caesar (N = 26), Elgamal(N is prime). And if a message value is greater than N, we must split it.

A simple example:

```
E(m) = m + 1 = c (mod 1009) => D(c) = c - 1 = m (mod 1009)
```

with

```
m = `"buazyhv"` = `546999123` (base-26 to base-10)
```

To avoid loss data (with modulo), I split to block of 3 digit:

```
M = (546)(999)(123) = m1m2m3
```

Now, encrypt each block

```
546 -> E -> 547
999 -> E -> 1000
123 -> E -> 124
```

Then we join it:

```
C = `5471000124` = "rsmetls"
```

For decryption, we do the same:

```
5 -> D -> 4
471 -> D -> 470
000 -> D -> 999
124 -> D -> 123
```

And we have the decypt message `M = 4470999123 = "omhwyat"`. So, my split and join message approach is not correct.

With another encrypt function like ElGamal (like `c = 980*m (mod 1009)`)

```
139 -> 980 * 139 = 5 (mod 1009) -> 005 (fill to 3 digit)
696 -> 980 * 696 = 1005 (mod 1009) -> 1005
```

So, if we found `m[i] == "005"`, we can't predict that it previous encrypt block is `"005"` or `"1005"`.

How can we encode/decode the ciphertext correctly in Java?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about cryptography and doesn't appear to have specific programming issue associated with it.

Comment: @Duncan I just rewrote the question slightly instead of closing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with these basic ciphers is that they are not defined to handle lots of (binary) data. Modern ciphers simply store binary, and they are combined with [modes of operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation) and padding modes to  handle data of almost arbitrary length. Furthermore, asymmetric ciphers are almost always used in a [hybrid cryptosystem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem), which let them handle arbitrary sizes data as well.

A Caesar cipher is a shift cipher that is defined on an alphabet. The simples and historically correct method of applying it is by specifying the ciphertext within the same alphabet. You should not represent it using numbers at all.

For ElGamal it is possible to use any method of encoding a set of numbers, as long as the method is able to distinguish the numbers. Using left padded numbers [as suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26542250/589259) is just one way. It is also possible to encode them as fixed sized binary (this is what e.g. RSA uses, see the [PKCS#1 specifications](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447#section-4.1)).

As text, probably the easiest way is to simply use a separator character and possibly white space for readability. Then you can simply use `String.split(",\\s*")` to retrieve the numbers. To make life easier, you can use [AbstractCollection.toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toString%28%29) for lists, or [Arrays.toString(int[])](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28int%5B%5D%29) for arrays (beware of the extra brackets). This is probably best for the toy ciphers as described here.

Example encoding/decoding:

```
public class ToyCiphertextCodec {
    private ToyCiphertextCodec() {
        // nothin' to do here
    }
    
    public static ToyCiphertextCodec getInstance() {
        return new ToyCiphertextCodec();
    }
    
    public String encode(int[] ciphertext) {
        // this is relatively lazy, probably better off creating the
        // encoding yourself if you are using this "in the field"
        return Arrays.toString(ciphertext);
    }
    
    public int[] decode(String encodedCiphertext) {
        if (!encodedCiphertext.startsWith("[") || !encodedCiphertext.endsWith("]")) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Ciphertext encoding invalid");
        }
        String encodedCiphertextWithoutBrackets = encodedCiphertext.substring(1, encodedCiphertext.length() - 1);
        String[] numbers = encodedCiphertextWithoutBrackets.split(", ");
        int[] intermediateResult = new int[numbers.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            intermediateResult[i] = Integer.parseInt(numbers[i]);
        }
        return intermediateResult;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ToyCiphertextCodec t = ToyCiphertextCodec.getInstance();
        
        int[] ciphertext = { 1, 2, 3 };
        String encodedCiphertext = t.encode(ciphertext);
        System.out.println(encodedCiphertext);
        
        int[] decodedCiphertext = t.decode(encodedCiphertext);
        System.out.println(Arrays.equals(ciphertext, decodedCiphertext));
    }
}
```

and just for fun:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ToyCiphertextCodecWithModulus {
    private final int sizeOfNumbers;
    private final String staticallySizedNumberFormat;
    
    private ToyCiphertextCodecWithModulus(int sizeOfNumbers) {
        this.sizeOfNumbers = sizeOfNumbers;
        this.staticallySizedNumberFormat = "%0" + sizeOfNumbers + "d";
    }
    
    public static ToyCiphertextCodecWithModulus getInstanceForModulus(int n) {
        int largestNumberOfDigits = String.valueOf(n - 1).length();
        return new ToyCiphertextCodecWithModulus(largestNumberOfDigits);
    }
    
    public String encode(int[] ciphertext) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(ciphertext.length * sizeOfNumbers);
        for (int i = 0; i < ciphertext.length; i++) {
            sb.append(String.format(staticallySizedNumberFormat, ciphertext[i]));
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
    
    public int[] decode(String encodedCiphertext) {
        if (encodedCiphertext.length() % sizeOfNumbers != 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Ciphertext encoding invalid");
        }
        
        int numbers = encodedCiphertext.length() / sizeOfNumbers;
        int[] intermediateResult = new int[numbers];
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers; i++) {
            String number = encodedCiphertext.substring(i * sizeOfNumbers, (i + 1) * sizeOfNumbers);
            intermediateResult[i] = Integer.parseInt(number);
        }
        return intermediateResult;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ToyCiphertextCodecWithModulus t = ToyCiphertextCodecWithModulus.getInstanceForModulus(997);
        
        int[] ciphertext = { 1, 2, 3 };
        String encodedCiphertext = t.encode(ciphertext);
        System.out.println(encodedCiphertext);
        
        int[] decodedCiphertext = t.decode(encodedCiphertext);
        System.out.println(Arrays.equals(ciphertext, decodedCiphertext));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution would be:

*After encryption*:

1. Split message to block of 3 (digit);
2. fill up to 4 digit of encrypted block.

*Before decryption*:

1. Split encrypted message to block of 4;
2. fill up to 3 digit of decrypted block.

But with this solution, it can gain a unnecessary '0' digit in the encrypted message if all encrypted block have only 3 digits...

Comment: Well, you cannot have your cake and eat it too. This is a relatively efficient (but less readable) method of storing the ciphertext, so +1 from me.

Comment: It pays to look a bit into markdown editing if you want to really get into stackoverflow. It works a lot nicer than HTML once you get into it, and it's pretty easy to learn.

Comment: Eh, why not just left pad up to 3 digits using zero digits and split on 3 digits each?